# in SwifUI how to define variables which depends of an input Entity in the init of a view and then populate different pickers

Tags: swiftui, core-data, binding, init, picker

I have a CoreData entity called PokSession which contains multiple attributes (date, currency, period, nbheure).
I want to design a view which display those informations (and allow me to modify them) for a given entity.
So basically from a previous view, I call an other view like this:

```
@FetchRequest(entity: PokSession.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \PokSession.date, ascending: false)
    ]) var poksessions: FetchedResults<PokSession>


ForEach(poksessions, id: \.date) { session in
     DetailSessionPokUIView (session: session)
  }
  .onDelete(perform: deleteSessions)
```

which leads to the following view:

```
struct DetailSessionPokUIView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

    @ObservedObject var session: PokSession

    @State private var date: Date
    @State private var currency: String
    @State private var periode: String
    @State private var nbheure: Double

    let liste_currency = ["CAD", "EUR", "USD", "GBP"]
    let liste_periode = ["matinée", "après-midi", "soirée"]

    init(session: PokSession) {
        
        date = session.date!
        currency = session.currency!
        periode = session.periode!
        nbheure = session.nbheure
    }

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    DatePicker(selection: $date , displayedComponents: .date){
                        Text("Date")
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Picker("Devise", selection: $currency) {
                            ForEach(liste_currency, id: \.self) { currency in
                                Text(currency)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Picker("Période de jeu", selection: $periode) {
                            ForEach(liste_periode, id: \.self) { periode in
                                Text(periode)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Text("Temps de jeu (h)")
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        Slider(value: $nbheure, in: 0...24, step: 1)
                        Text("\(nbheure, specifier: "%.0f")")
                        Image(systemName: "clock")
                    }

                }
            }   // Form
        }       // NavigationView

    }
}
```

But I am having error message inside my init(), saying " Variable 'self.session' used before being initialized".
I dont really understand why as "session" is an input in my init().

- How can I use attributes of the selected PokSection entity to populate my DatePicker and my other Pickers default value

It shouldn't be difficult I guess but I am struggling...

Basically, I just want to have my Pickers set with the value coming from the selected PokSession.
And I want to see it in a Picker because I want to be able to modify it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You haven't set `self.session`. First line of your init should likely be `_session = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: session)`. But, it's unclear if you really need this reference anyway. If you are only setting the `@State` variables, just remove the `@ObservedObject` line

Comment: Or the opposite, skip the State properties and work directly with your ObservedObject property.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But @jnpdx, Even if I write:
    init(session: PokSession) {
        _session = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: session)
        date = session.date!
        currency = session.currency!
        periode = session.periode!
        nbheure = session.nbheure
    }
I still have the same errors saying Variable 'self.date' used before being initialized (idem for others variables from init).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thank you. I tried to work directly with my ObservedObject property. It's fine if I just want to display them. But I use them in a picker like Picker("Devise", selection: $session.currency) {...}
The selection in the picker is suppose to be $session.currency but It shows always the first value of my list of currencies, but not the one saved in that session. (for text display, with Text(session.wrappedCurrency), it works. But not in the picker...

Comment: I think I misunderstood your code a bit, working with @State objects should be the best way forward.

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson, I agree that I have to work with State objects to be able to use them in Pickers. But How can I set them (initiate them) with a default value coming from the properties of "session". Also, I want to be able to modify those values and save them back into "session" (that's why I want to use Pickers also).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson do you have any idea to help me regarding my comment to jnpdx ?